# How is the phrase "$n$-bit number" related to the big $O$ notation?

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

When it comes to algorithms, you frequently have to evaluate problems like this:

> Let $x$ be an $n$-bit integer. For each of the following questions, give your answer as a function of $n$.

Or a question like this:

> [given algorithm] Assume that the subtraction takes $O(n)$ time on an $n$-bit number.

What does "let $x$ be an $n$-bit integer" really mean? It is just the amount of bits reserved for a random int variable $x$?
How does the $n$-bit number relate to the big $O$ of $n$ notation?

Answer (score 5):

We usually represent numbers as finite sequence of digits. In base-$2$ each digit is called bit and has value $0$ or $1$. So we write each number $a$ as $\sum_{k=0}^n a_i2^i$, where $a_i$ are digits and assuming $a_n\neq0$ number $a$ is called $n$-bit number. Notice that if $a$ is $n$-bit number then $2^{n-1}\leq a<2^n$. So number of bits of number $a$ is $O(\log a)$.

If algorithm works on individual digits, then the complexity is dependant on length of given number (by length I mean number of bits). For instance how does addition algorithm works? You want to add $a$ and $b$, first you add $a_0$ and $b_0$, write down the result, if necessary carry $1$, continue for next bit and so on. As a result you do $n$ bit additions, so adding two $n$-bit numbers has complexity $O(n)$.

So basicly, saying that algorithm takes time $O(n)$ for $n$-digit number, means that it is linear with respect to the length of given number. And also that it takes time $O(\log n)$ with respect to the number itself.

Comment: ohh its starting to make sense now, see i was unaware that n bit binary is n additions cause you have to add the bits one by one (seeing as i do most adding in decimal notation and there i dont even think about it since its so elementary). what is the $O(log n)$ notation you speak of, i don't get it.

Comment: @notamathwiz Notice that when you multiply a number by 2, its length increases by 1. So if number $n$ has $k$ digits, then $k=O(\log n)$ and if algorithm takes time $O(k)$ (linear with respect to number of bits), then it is also running in time $O(\log n)$ (with respect to that number).

Answer (score 2):

It asks you how does the space/time of algorithm evaluation growth with $n$. O(n) means linear dependency. $O(n^2)$ is square dependency, $O(e^n)$ is exponential.

Comment: i understand that part, im just trying to grasp the deeper most fundamental meaning of the n-bit int.

Comment: It sounds like you are asking about fundamental dependency between a and b in $a = f(b)$ for abstract function $f$.

Comment: im question is geared more toward understanding what you said about "the growth of n" what does that really mean, does that mean that the more data we input the more n growths? how does that relate to n? say we have a data set that has 10 integers and n-bit is 32-bit does that mean that the space we need to allocate is 320 bits? that's what im trying to understand.

Comment: O(n) means that you may need c*O(n) bits in your computer. Your computer must have size c*n "bits" for n-bit numbers and c*m "bits" for m-bit arguments. It is not about datasets. It about a single parameter. If you have m numbers, n bits each, then you'll have some O(m,n). Likewise O(n) it is not always linear.

Comment: particluarly for 10x32 this means that you can add your 10 numbers together one by one, in O(10) time using 32-bit computer (space) or do the addition in parallel in O(m,n)~log(10) time using O(m,n)~10x32 computer.

Answer (score 1):

$n$ is used for the sake of scaling things in terms of bits.  If you didn't know the size of $x$, then lots of complexities would have to be expressed as a log base 2 as you don't know how many bits $x$ has unless it is expressed this way.  Consider the question of how many addition operations have to be done on $a$ and $b$ where the addition is done base 2 though the numbers are in base 10?  First, you want to know how long is each number in base 2, which could be seen as $n_a$ and $n_b$ which makes the answer the maximum of these values plus one as if the numbers are the same length there may be a carry bit to factor into things here.

---

The intention of Big O is to understand in the worst case how does the complexity grow relative to the size of the input, often denoted as $n$.  [Sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) would be one of the classic problems that has been studied to great lengths in terms of the number of comparisons that have to be done in order to sort a list.

Just to give a couple of examples, first consider the [BubbleSort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) algorithm where the algorithm is to compare a pair of elements, and if a pair change order, start all over again at the beginning.  So, for example consider this list of numbers that are to be sorted in descending order:

2 5 3 7

Comparing 2 and 5, these aren't in the proper order so we reverse these 2 elements and start again.

5 2 3 7

Comparing 5 and 2, these are in the proper order.  Next, we compare 2 and 3 which aren't in the right order and have to be reversed and then we start again.

5 3 2 7

Comparing 5 and 3, these are in the proper order.  Next, we compare 3 and 2 which are also in the proper order.  Next, 2 and 7 are compared and have to be reversed.

5 3 7 2

Comparing 5 and 3, these are in the right order.  Next, 3 and 7 are compared and have to be reversed.

5 7 3 2

Comparing 5 and 7, these aren't in the right order and so we reverse these now.

7 5 3 2

Now, the comparisons all work out and the list is sorted.  Notice all the comparisons that had to be done which in the worst case will be $O(n^2)$ as if the list is in reverse order, there are a quadratic number of comparisons to be done.

In contrast, take that list and apply [MergeSort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort):

2 5 3 7

After the initial split and sort each half, as the idea is divide and conquer here:

5 2 7 3

Now, merge the lists:

7 5 3 2

Merge is better in overall complexity in the worst case as the divisions reduce the comparisons to being $O(n \log n)$ which is slightly better.

---

In your example, if the number of repetitions is constant, then the big O stays the same.  However, if the loop was for each bit within a loop for each bit within a loop for each bit, then the complexity is likely to be $O(n^3)$ unless the iterator for the loop is incrementing in a non linear fashion.

Comment: what about a $O(n^2)$? say you have a loop that cycles two times and in the loop you add two x integers that are n-bit. does that mean the big Oh notation is the one above?